# re-time collection instance?

Tags: collections

I'm working on a large scale mograph project and am hoping to re-use and re-time an animated collection which includes numerous objects moving along curves via path animation and offset factor.

Let's call this collection MASTER_collection: The path animations in this collection run from frame 0 to frame 250.

What I'm looking to do is to retime instances of this Master_collection.

IE: The first instanced collection may run from 0 to 250 (just like MASTER_collection), but the second instanced collection would be delayed to run 100 frames later.

While I'm well aware I could just duplicate this Master_Collection and slide the keyframe values in the graph editor, I was hoping there might be a more elegant solution involving instanced collections because by the end of this project I'll have 100 different collections spanning multiple projects and the duplicate/keyframe slide method is bound to get messier much more quickly.

Comment: Please show your work as a Blender screen capture.  Show the graph editor and relevant keyframes. Have you used the Graph Editor?  Do you have keyframes?  The graph editor allows you to move keyframes quickly.  You may choose to see a beginner tutorial here on BSE or free online video on how to use the graph editor.  There is a good site with a name that rhymes with noonoob.

Comment: Haha, yes to all that. I updated the question for more info. It was just stab in the dark to save some time. Rawk on!

Comment: The theoretical short cut often becomes the long extension

Comment: Scripts can create keyframes based on some or zero external data.  There is the NLA which can be searched.  Are the actions of this data very customized or rather on the random side?  How many collection are necessary in the 3D viewport at once?